# C#, Announce class settings to GUI

Tags: c#, design-patterns

### Context

I am working on a C# project where I have several electrical instruments such as Power supplies and Voltmeters.

There are multiple choices for each instrument, for instance, we have two different type of power supplies. We only connect to one of each type for every run.

In the design that I have in mind, I would like to have a common interface for each type, for instance

```
public interface PSU
{
    public void connect();
    public void disconnect();
    ...
}
```

Next, in my GUI I will register all the available PSU units which will show up under a menu item and in that menu item, only one of them can be selected for each type.

Next what I would like to do is for the units to announce their settings in a way that the GUI can create a submenu out of those settings.
My goal is to have it like this, if I add another PSU for instance, I would only need to register it.

---

### Questions

- How do I provide the settings in a way that can be turned into menus?
- How do I connect menu event(s) to these dynamically created submenus? These events should actually update the instrument settings.
- Is this even a valid and maintainable idea?

<sup>Thank you</sup>

Comment: As already mentioned in an answer comment below, learning about classes, interfaces and inheritance is invaluable.  That knowledge alone answers most of this question.  Then you only need reflection to find relevant classes and create menu items for them.  It's a lot to learn, but very little code once you understand it.  Good luck & have fun :)

Comment: Thank you. I'll start learning then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could via reflection check which classes implement your IPSU (Allways start an interface with a capital I it helps maintain, I swear.)

something like this perhaps?

```
var type = typeof(IPSU);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

Then of course you would likely need to use the activator to create an instance of said types, and then pass them to a menu class, perhaps a controller?

you could make an IConvertToMenu, that implements all the values required to build your particular menu.

Thats how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you give a short example or point me to somewhere that I can read about it? Thank you

Comment: I just googled guide, reflection and C# and this link seems promising:

http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/reflection/introduction/

Note that if you don't have a basic grasp of what classes, instances and interfaces are, this might be a bit hard to understand. (I don't know your skill level)